# Django models, finding matches from a list

Tags: django, list, django-models

I have a model:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,primary_key=True)
    #Some other fields....
```

Then i get from another query, or from some other source, a list of names:

```
['bob','dylan','jane','doe']
```

How can i select from the database the tags with the names from the list ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Tag.objects.filter(name__in=['bob','dylan','jane','doe']
)`

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [`in`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in) keyword.

Comment: in what ? and don't you need a minimum character limit ? :)

Comment: Didn't see the link ... looked gray on my screen :) Thanks.